# Stretch text in texblock with Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, textblock, stretch

The size of the content of my textblock is too long so I would like to cut the text which not fit inside the textblock and replace its end by "...".
What is the best solution to stretch a text ?
 I would prefer to not have to do this with codebehind.Maybe is there a property but I didn't find it.

I already tried to use the FontStretch property in vain...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TextTrimming property of textblock. [Here](http://nerdplusart.com/texttrimming-textblock-for-silverlight/) is more about TextTrimming

```
<TextBlock  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Text="your text" />
```

Comment: Great thanks, couple this property with textWrapping to do the work